# Make a _Layout link differ in its action when it is used on a different page?

Tags: jquery, html, layout

Say I have the layout page of (which is common in all pages):

```
+------------------------------------+
|         HEADER                     |
+------------------------------------+
| N |                                |
| A |                                |
| V |         CONTENT                |
| B |          HERE                  |
| A |                                |
| R |                                |
|   |                                |
|   |                                |
+------------------------------------+
|        FOOTER                      |
+------------------------------------+
```

And within my header I have something like:

**Header:**

```
+------------------------------------------------
|
|    LINK_1 | Create | Edit | Remove
|
+-----------------------------------------
|                |
|                |
|
```

Whenever I go onto the 'locations' page, I want it to run the function 'AddLocation' function, but when it's on the 'Users' page, I want it to run the function 'AddUser' function.

Is this possible? (pressing the button on the _Layout page and it do something different depending on which content is being displayed at the time)?

If so, how should I be implementing this? On the _layout header? The specific function on each of the Locations/Users page itself?

## Alternative

If this ***isn't*** possible, how about creating a switch statement depending on the address value?

i.e.

```
localHost/Locations //pressing it here will addLocation
localHost/Users     //pressing it here instead will addUser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

**1 Custom section (preferred)**

Using a custom `section` makes the most sense for you as it is optional and requires little setup:

In the layout where you want the button:

```
@RenderSection("addoption", required: false)
```

Then anywhere in your `users` view pages:

```
@section addoption{
   @Html.ActionLink("Add User", "adduser", "Users")
}
```

and in your `location` view pages

```
@section addoption{
   @Html.ActionLink("Add Location", "addlocation", "Location")
}
```

**2 ViewBag**

Another option is to pass the desired link values to the layout, from a specific controller action, using the `ViewBag`. This requires setup in multiple places.

e.g. in the layout page:

```
@Html.ActionLink(@ViewBag.AddTitle, @ViewBag.AddAction, @ViewBag.AddController)
```

and in the locations index action something like:

```
  ViewBag.AddTitle = "Add location";
  ViewBag.AddAction = "AddLocation";
  ViewBag.AddController = "Locations";
```

and in the Users index action something like:

```
  ViewBag.AddTitle = "Add user";
  ViewBag.AddAction = "AddUser";
  ViewBag.AddController = "Users";
```

**3 Action Only**

Another simple option is for your link to simply reference an `add` action with no controller.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", "add")
```

this will call the `add` action *on the current controller*. You can combine this with part of option 2 to set just the link text using a `ViewBag` value.

Comment: I'm thinking the first is possible, but I just have to laugh because I keep reading 'addoption' as 'adoption'. I've also neglected to mention in my question that i'm using images/icons as the links, but shouldn't involve too much editing from there.

Comment: That is funny :) Always do images on links via styling (if possible).

Comment: I'm not sure if my set up quite allows that - except adding the 5-6 images separately (same really as adding them inline I suppose). I'll look into the '@RenderSection' to see how that's working

Comment: You can inject any code/HTML into a `RenderSection` from any view, so that is the most flexible. Bit like a tiny PartialView. Have fun with it :)

Comment: Is it also possible to inject `<script>` as well?

Comment: Yes, but be aware the script will be injected into that part of the page, so make sure (if it is jQuery/JS) you wrap it in a DOM ready handler or load handler if it precedes the elements it references.

Comment: Thank you for your help, and also the advise you've given! Cheers:)